# Hercules DJ console MK4

Tags: music, disk, console, jockey

I have a Hercules DJ console MK4 at home and I would like to use it in Ubuntu because I prefer this over Windows.

I know it isn't officially supported but does anyone know any method to do this?
I'm in Ubuntu 12.04

greets

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to get it running.

Have a look at the hardware compatibility wiki of mixxx:
http://www.mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/hardware_compatibility

and the corresponding internas, where the technical problem for a linux driver seems to be:
http://www.mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/hardware_compatibility#fn__16

Comment: thnx for your command,
I'm going to have a look but i think it won't work if i understand you correctly :s

Answer (score 0):

now is working but you have to wait for 1.12.0 or patch then recompile.

Comment: Could you provide the source of your statement? And what patch? And how to apply it and recompile?

Comment: @gertvdijk all your answer can be found here: http://mixxx.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5064&start=10 good luck!